# form_open method not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have try to action control/method but `form_open` method are not working I have loaded helper

hello.php  controller

```
<?php

class hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view("fv");
    }

    public function f_validation() {
        echo "hello";

    }
}

?>
```

**fv.php** view file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php echo form_open('hello/f_validation'); ?>
    <h5>Username</h5>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="">

    <h5>Password</h5>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="" >

    <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
    <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" >

    <h5>Email Address</h5>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" >

    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use Like this**

```
 <?php
    class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function index() 
    {
       $this->load->view("fv");
    }

    public function f_validation() 
    {
      echo "hello";

    }
 }
```

**See This :**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html#loading-a-helper

Comment: correct answer, but class name should start with capital letter. `Hello`